# "spurious" leading in latex

Tags: latex

the following latex input:

```
\rule{1cm}{1cm}\\
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
```

leaves a gap of about .35mm between the boxes. what is the length that defines this gap?

Comment: +1 for asking a LaTeX question! More LaTeX to the people!

Comment: I think you mean "hear hear!!" 
…grumble… :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I was only partly right at first, but GoogleBooks knew. It pointed me at *A Beginner's Book of TeX*
 By Raymond Seroul, Silvio Levy, Silvio Vieira Ferreira Levy, which says:

> Three variables control this behavior `\baselineskip`, `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit`.

The default separation of lines is `\baselineskip`, but boxes are not allowed to come closer than `\lineskiplimit`. If they would, the vertical spacing is adjusted until `\lineskip` space lies between them...